# In Dark Matter s02e08 (SPOILER ALERT!!), Regarding Jace Corso

Tags: dark-matter

In s02e08, in the alternate reality, isn’t Jace Corso supposed to be good? After all, he is

> Derrick Moss

In this episode he seems evil. Why?

Comment: I don't follow this series, but that title seems spoilerish.

Comment: Yes, your right, ive changed the header of the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't know whether this is the real Jace Corso or not but its probably safe to assume it is.

Jace Corso is a real person whose identity was assumed by Derrick Moss (One)

From the [**Wikia**](http://darkmatter.wikia.com/wiki/Jace_Corso_(Original))

> Jace told them that he was supposed to go with the Raza and its crew to the job on the Mining Colony but **wasn't able to make it**. He had since learned that he had supposedly boarded the ship, and had then viewed security footage that showed One boarding the ship in his place. He had pursued One ever since.

Perhaps in this alternate reality, he could make it...we just don't know, but again, based on his actions etc, it's safe to assume this is the real Jace and not One.

[**Syfy**](http://www.syfy.com/darkmatter/blog/dark-matter-fun-facts-season-2-episode-8) seems to indicate that this is in fact Alt-Jace and not Alt-Derrick/One

> You can't keep Marc Bendavid away from Dark Matter for too long. One got killed off, Jace Corso got killed off, but now we've got ... Alternate **Jace Corso!**

Comment: Update from S03E06: One Last Card to Play: AU Wexler says Jace did not come back with them on the Marauder attached to the hull of the Raza.